# swiftui: textfield in HStack, when tap the textfield, the code in ontapgesture of HStack is also executed

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

```
HStack {
   textfield("", text: $text)
   Text("Something")
}
.onTapGesture {
   code
}
```

How can I focus the textfield without executing the codes in onTapGesture?
please help me, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I come with following idea, it's simple and maybe temporary solution. Just Add onTapGesture Action on TextField so it will execute that and does not execute action on HStack.

```
       HStack {
            TextField("", text: $text).onTapGesture {
                print("Tap On TextField")
            }
           Text("Something")
        }
        .onTapGesture {
           print("Tap On HStack")
        }
```

If we tap on Text("Something") it will execute HStack onTapGesture Action.

Update : -

WE can also do something like following :

```
    HStack {
        TextField("", text: $text).onTapGesture {
            print("Tap On TextField")
        }
       Group {
            Text("Something")
            // Add Other Item here
       }.onTapGesture {
            print("Tap On Group")
       }
    }
```

This simply make 2 groups in Hstack and on Textfield Tap if you don't want any action then simply don't put any action on it. Put Your action on Other Group.

Comment: why do all this, put the `onTapGesture{}` on `Text("Something")` then.

Comment: What if there are multiple items in HStack? Then we have to put onTapGesture on Every other item. So to avoid that I did it.

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot~ it solves my problem, but i still want to ask that are there any ways to limit the “tap area” or set some limitations to achieve that？

Comment: Tap area covers exactly the view's area, where you put the tap handler.

Comment: Yes, in my project, there are multiple items in HStack.

Comment: Your welcome @YiweiPing, You can try something i updated as well.

Comment: Thanks again!~ your suggestions really help me! Thanks!!!!!!!!